# Chef: Read variable from file and use it in one converge

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have the following code which downloads a file and then reads the contents of the file into a variable.  Using that variable, it executes a command.  This recipe will not converge because /root/foo does not exist during the compile phase.

I can workaround the issue with multiple converges and an

> if File.exist

but I would like to do it with one converge.  Any ideas on how to do it?

```
execute 'download_joiner' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/foo /root/foo"
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/root/foo') }
end

password = ::File.read('/root/foo').chomp

execute 'join_domain' do
  command "net ads join -U joiner%#{password}"
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can download the file at compile time by using run_action and wrap the second part in the conditional block which will be executed at run time.

```
execute 'download_joiner' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/foo /root/foo"
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/root/foo') }
end.run_action(:run)

if File.exist?('/root/foo')
  password = ::File.read('/root/foo').chomp

  execute 'join_domain' do
    command "net ads join -U joiner%#{password}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

The correct solution is to use a lazy property:

```
execute 'download_joiner' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/foo /root/foo"
  creates '/root/foo'
  sensitive true
end


execute 'join_domain' do
  command lazy {
    password = IO.read('/root/foo').strip
    "net ads join -U joiner%#{password}"
  }
  sensitive true
end
```

That delays the file read until after it is written. Also I included the `sensitive` property so the password is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file from the second command, so that reading happens during convergence too:

```
execute 'download_joiner' do
  command "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/foo /root/foo"
  not_if { ::File.exist?('/root/foo') }
end

execute 'join_domain' do
  command "net ads join -U joiner%`cat /root/foo`"
end
```

Note that both your approach and mine will break if the password contains funny characters. If `net` lets you provide the password on stdin or an env var, I'd do that instead.